# Detect actual web page size in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html

I need to find a way to get actual page size in Google Chrome. In other browsers this can be easily done with window.scrollMaxY. Chrome does not support this property. All proposed workrounds, which I found so far, do not work as expected. Here is a simple test page (insert this into empty html/body element):

```
<input type="button" name="size" value="size" onclick="alert(window.scrollMaxY)">
<div id="content" style="width:300px;height:500px;background-color:green"></div>
```

We have a div with height 500. In FireFox, no matter what is the size of the browser window, the code returns actual height of the page, that is 500 + some value for margins and the button. In Chrome we need to replace `window.scrollMaxY` with something. I've tried all mentioned on the Net properties (document.body, document.documentElement, window.getComputedStyle, and others), but no one returns actual height of the document, **when Chrome window is larger than the document**: in this case any property provided by Chrome returns the height of the window, not the height of the page. For example, if we have a screen with 768 pixels height, and Chrome window maximized, Chrome will report the page height about 700, not 500.
So the question is, how to get actual page size in Chrome. Feel free to test your propositions with the specified test page, replacing the alert's parameter with any necessary stuff.

Self-answer:

After deeper investigation I found that the cause of the problem is the web-page itself, specifically the missing DOCTYPE tag in the beginning of the page. Without the DOCTYPE Chrome works in a different mode, and expands the body to entire window (as zapthedingbat wrote in his answer). So, the proper web-page markup may solve the problem, but it is only possible in the cases when the pages are our own pages. For other peoples' web-pages from Internet, which may have no DOCTYPE, the problem will persist. As I need to deel with external web-pages, I'll need to solve this somehow, but this is another question.

I hope this info may be helpful for others who stumble on the same issue and can't figure out the reason.

Comment: The final solution is found here - http://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/30/jquery-change-doctype/. For documents in BackCompat mode DOCTYPE is dynamically added, and only after this `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` works as expected in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems simple, but there is a case in which all standard methods do not work as expected. The cause of the problem is the web-page with missing DOCTYPE tag in the beginning. Without the DOCTYPE modern browsers work in a special (quirks) mode, and expands the body to entire window. So, the proper web-page markup may solve the problem, but it is not guaranteed for other people's pages that come from the Internet (and processed, for example, by a browser extension). The solution is to add DOCTYPE on the fly, as it is suggested here - [jquery-change-doctype](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/30/jquery-change-doctype). For documents in BackCompat mode DOCTYPE is dynamically added, and only after this `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` works as expected in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are using `$(document).ready()` as opposed to `$(window).load()` ?

I'd give `$(window).load()` a go first, as it executes once ***everything*** has finished loading, not just the DOM.

Just tested this in Chrome:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    console.log($('body').height());
});
```

It returned 500.

Comment: For this simple test I provided a page with a button, so the checkup can be surely run after the page is loaded completely. Binding to any of the mentioned events does not change the result. The prototypes's getHeight() doesn't work either.

Comment: For this simple test, it returns the right answer. Can you provide more information on what *isn't* is working? Perhaps show us some code?

Comment: The code is inserted in the initial post. Did you maximize Chrome window, before pressing the button? What value do you get?

Comment: What is the "content" element in your example? I tried against body, because I need entire page size.

Comment: `console.log($('body').height()); 522` - still returns the right size.

Comment: Did you maximize browser window before this?

Comment: Well, then I don't know how to explain this... Here it works differently. What operation system (Windows/Linux) and version of Chrome do you use?

Comment: I'm using OSX at the moment, Chrome version 16.0.912.77. I have also tested this on a windows system too. Same Chrome version. The windows system returns 526 as a height.

Comment: Strange. I also use Chrome 16 on Windows, and get 689.

Comment: Kyle, could you please describe your test-case with more detailes? I added a reference to latest jquery and inserted your code snippet into headers' script tag. I tried this test on a different PC and it still gives window size instead of the page's. Also could you please explain the answer of zapthedingbat below? If he is right, the test can't work.

Answer (score 0):

try using following code;

```
alert(document.body.offsetHeight);
```

this is very crossbrowser friendly and will give you the actual height of the content (not the viewport!).

In rare situations, this could "fail", if you only have ´position:absolute´ elements within the body. But that would be the expected situation, because ´position:absolute´ elements are outside of the normal layout.

Comment: This does not work (return window size, not page size). Apparently you did not try it yourself.

Comment: ähm?! a abit more appreciation to my answer (and to the others) wouldn't be asking to much!
Yes, I actually tested it and yes, it actually works in chrome. And yes, I use that code on a website that has 30mio Impressions a day and believe it or not, it actually works.
Window Size (ViewPort Size) is detected with document.documentElement.innerHeight. Page Size is detected with document.body.offsetHeight. AND AGAIN; if you have position:absolute elements on your page, THIS WILL FAIL, because it should!

Comment: There is no position:absolute in the styles. For the simplicity I provided the very minimal test-page, you can check yourself. I suppose you did not notice my remark about browser window which should be larger than page content. Otherwise, you are right, but not in the given conditions.

Comment: There are 2 lines of html-code in my inital post. This is all I have in the web-page. Do you mean, I need to attach html-file somehow? After this, according to Kyle's suggetions, I pasted his code with `$(window).load` (bound to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js). But both methods return window size (700+) on different PCs I have for testing. I'm not sure what else could be helpful in solving this problem (for example, there is no extensions and plugins in my test Chrome instances which may interfere somehow).

Answer (score 0):

`document.height` will give you the height of the document in chrome. Is that what you're looking for?

---

**EDIT**

In chrome the body expands to fill the viewport. If you want to get the height of the contents then either wrap the contents of the body in a single element and read the offsetHeight property of this wrapping element or iterate over each childNode of the body and return the maximum offsetHeight + offsetTop properties.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If window is larger than page, it returns window size.